# Collisions with groups of sprites

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have a class defined which represents a list of characters, the methods in this class are simple:

```
addCharacter(Character)
removeCharacter(Character)
addCharacters(Character, number)
removeCharacters(Character,number)
```

This class uses an associative array to append and remove characters. They all do what they are meant to do. However now I have reached the collisions stage I am unable to deifine a function wrapper for any of the methods given by pygame like `spritecollideany`.

When I try to test if there is a collision between a singular object and a charactersList and try to remove when a collision occurs all the objects in that list is removed not the one that has been collided with.

So

```
troll = Characters()
monster = Characters()
monsters = CharactersList(monster)

monster.addCharacters(monster,3)
```

to check for collision

```
if troll.collidesWith(monsters):
      for mon in monsters:
          mon.removeCharacter()
          screen.remove_character(mon)
```

The collision function which is in the character class looks like this:

```
from CharactersList import *
def collideswith(self,CharactersList):
        collision = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, CharactersList)
        return collision
```

Even if i replace the associative array with a sprite group which is meant for this

```
self.sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(Character)
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve collision with sprite groups in this way, such that when an object collides with one in that group, only that object is removes?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You are trying to modify `monsters` while iterating over it; and
2. You are checking whether the `troll` collides with a `mon`, but want to remove the latter.

It might be better to check whether each `mon` collides with the `troll`, store the monsters to remove, then remove them all:

```
if troll.collidesWith(monsters): # some monsters will need removing
    removals = []
    for mon in monsters: # figure out which
        if mon.collidesWith(GroupSingle(troll)):
            removals.append(mon)
    for mon in removals: # remove them
        mon.removeCharacter()
        screen.remove_character(mon)
```

Comment: what if the trolls are meant to grab a monster, same principle applies?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Generally, you should check the object you want to remove for collisions to simplify your code.

Comment: this is okay, but it doest work with the collision function i have provided

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe said, you should not modify monsters list while iterating over it - you can make a copy of it :

```
for mon in list(monsters):
    if mon.collideswith([troll]):
        mon.removeCharacter()
```

But, how about trying a pygame.sprite.groupcollide() method? 
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide

```
# that would remove monsters that have collided with troll
groupcollide(troll, monsters, False, True)
```

If you would like to use that method, please make sure that your sprite objects have a rect value, as it is said in documentation. It is required for calculate the collision between objects.